# @PreUpdate does not work with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
class MyEntity{ ... }
```

And the listener:

```
class MyEntityListener{
    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    public void doSomething(Object entity){ ... }
}
```

I'm using the Spring Data generated DAO for this entity (1.4.1) and EclipseLink. The code behavior is as follows:

```
MyEntity entity = new Entity();
entity = dao.save(entity); // the doSomething() is called here
// change something it the entity and save it again
dao.save(entity); // the doSomething() is NOT called here, checked with breakpoint
```

The problem has already been [described by someone in 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20190225014303/http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/123850-preupdate-not-working), however, they did not came up with any solution. I wonder if anyone has and idea how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure that `doSomething()` is not called at all for the second time? It may be called prior to transaction commit, not immediately.

Comment: Have you tried to detach the entity before the second save()?

Comment: @AndreiI you are right, when I get the entity by `entity = dao.findOne(entity.getId())` before saving it the second time, listener's method is called successfully. Please post it as an answer, and the reason if you know what's going on.

Comment: I'm using `JpaRepository`, calling `repository.saveAndFlush(entity)` did fire `@PreUpdate` callback. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said, the callback method **is called** the second time, if the entity is detached or fetched again from DB.

I cannot explain it exactly, but can think of the scenario described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877499/eclipselink-jpa-preupdate-call-not-persisting), when no dirty fields are identified before the second `save()` call and thus the @PreUpdate callback not called. Or it may be simply a bug within your version of EclipseLink.

---

**UPDATE**

In the JPA 2.0 specification I found the following, which is exactly your behaviour (3.5.2 Semantics of the Life Cycle Callback Methods for Entities):

> Note that it is implementation-dependent as to whether PreUpdate and
>   PostUpdate call- backs occur when an entity is persisted and
>   subsequently modified in a single transaction or when an entity is
>   modified and subsequently removed within a single transaction.
>   Portable applications should not rely on such behavior.

Answer (score 2):

what is your transactional setting around your two different save()?

I think there would be some differnce between save()/update()/merge()/persist(), for the different status of an entity(transient, persistent, detached), the operations is not the same as you thought and your annotation @PrePersist and @PreUpdate did not take effect.

Comment: I have Spring's transaction management turned on, but the flushing seems not to be a problem because when I replace both `save` calls with `saveAndFlush` there is no difference.

Comment: after your first save, the entity is still in persistent status. maybe saveOrUpdate() can resovle your problem.

Comment: `saveOrUpdate()` in neither in the `JpaRepository` nor in the `CrudRepository` interfaces.

Comment: Is there a way to detach the pesistent entity before you do a second save?

Comment: I'm not sure this link works for your case
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588565/spring-data-jpa-why-are-changes-to-a-returned-entity-automatically-persisted
is there a method EntityManager.detach()?

Comment: Fetching the entity again from database before saving it the second time solves the problem. See my comment above to Andreil.